# What's the name of this praying type sitting posture?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

[image]

[image]

What's the name of this praying type sitting posture? May be sad.

Comment: "With the head bowed on the folded hands."

Comment: There are questions about the practice on Christianity Stack Exchange and Wikipedia has articles on bowing and hand clasping, but I can't see a more concise name than head bowed and hands clasped. (The posture seems restricted to some branches of Christianity and there are suggestions it's medieval in origin, but nobody seems to have named it.)  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/23025/why-do-folks-clasp-their-hands-and-bow-their-heads-when-praying https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2007/what-is-the-origin-of-praying-hands-folded

Comment: I agree with Stuart F: there probably is no name for it, but if there is, the Christianity SE would be the place to ask. It would be helpful to close and move the post or for the OP to repost it in Christianity SE. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/